# Opening a folder from PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I can embed elements in PowerPoint and assign actions to them, e.g. run a program. However, if I enter a directory name, it does not open the directory.

I tried:

- directory name only
- `start` + directory name

How can I open an directory from an action on an element in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start` and directory name was already close. This works:

- cmd /c start <directoryname>

However, the nicer way seems to be starting Explorer directly:

- explorer <directoryname>